# Rails has_and_belongs_to_many how to change default iforeign key and show list of results on csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have tables products and suppliers. And a joining table products_sup.

I have in my model Product:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :suppliers, :join_table => "products_sup"
```

And in my model Supplier:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :products, :join_table => "products_sup"
```

In my view I would like to display list of suppliers for each product.

But it returns

> Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'products_sup.product_id' in 'on clause':

Note that NAME is a column in suppliers db table. And products_sup is the joining table.

The problem is that products_sup contains columns PRODUCT, SUPPLIER. While rails by default is looking for supplier_id and product_id. But I can't find the right syntax to change these default columns. The same way that for a belongs_to I would use `:foreign_key => 'custom_foreign_key_column'

What should I use in my view and models to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In product model use:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :suppliers, join_table: 'products_sup', association_foreign_key: 'SUPPLIER', foreign_key: 'PRODUCT'
```

In suppliers model use:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :products, join_table: 'products_sup', association_foreign_key: 'PRODUCT', foreign_key: 'SUPPLIER'
```

In your view you need to give consideration on how you wish to display the suppliers but if you want to simply show them as a comma, separated list in your current table you could always do:

```
<td><%= product.suppliers.map {|supplier| supplier.NAME }.join(', ') %></td>
```

Failing that consider using through: instead of join_table for greater control over customising joins.