# Rails has_and_belongs_to_many on 2 level association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

This is related to this previously asked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40328322/rails-has-and-belongs-to-many-how-to-change-default-iforeign-key-and-show-list-o)

I have a has_and_belongs_to_many in place between Product and Supplier.

In my view I use:

```
<td><%= product.suppliers.map {|supplier| supplier.NAME }.join(', ') %></td>
```

To show list of suppliers comma separated on each row for each product in my table.

I now need to show the same list on invoices index view. Invoices table has a column PRODUCT. I have already set belongs_to :product on Invoice model.

I tried in my invoices index view:

```
<td><%= invoice.product.suppliers.map {|supplier| product.supplier.NAME }.join(', ') %></td>
```

but it returns

> error undefined local variable or method `product'

Why isn't that working? How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is each invoice only for a single product? That sounds wrong. Usually you would have something like an InvoiceLineItem model to relate invoices to products. Btw, for your first query try: product.suppliers.map(&:NAME).to_sentence (Is the name really upper case?)

Comment: That was just an example to give the idea. Real database yes has invoice line. Column name is uppercase is not a typo. Your solution worked but I had to add `invoice.` in front. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you build wrong `.map`, try

```
invoice.product.suppliers.pluck(:NAME).join(', ')
```

BTW

it's bad practice use logic in view, you should move your logic to models, and in view use something like:

```
<%= invoice.suppliers_names %>
```

what should return `# => 'Name_1, Name_2, etc'`

Comment: Ok perfect it works in view. Then I created `def suppliers_name
    suppliers_name = self.product.suppliers.pluck(:NAME).join(', ')
  end` so that now everything is moved to the model. Thanks a lot!